# EKEvent edit not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, ekeventkit

I am working on EKEvent in iOS5. I am able to add, delete, list events but now the problem is when I try to edit an existing event, the "Done" button creates problems. It is not going inside eventEditViewController: method. What might be the problem? Any help will be appreciated. Cancel and Delete button are working. When I edit the event and click "Done", the console shows
`Calendar: unable to save: (null)` .

Here is the code I tried..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    EKEventEditViewController* eventViewController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
    event = [self.events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    eventViewController.event = event;
    eventViewController.editViewDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController: eventViewController animated:YES];
    [eventViewController release];
}

-(void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller
         didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action {
    EKEvent *thisEvent = controller.event;
    NSError *error;
    if ([controller.event.endDate isEqualToDate:controller.event.startDate]) {
        controller.event.endDate = [controller.event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:1.0]; // add one second
    }
    switch (action) {
        case EKEventEditViewActionCancelled:
            // User tapped "cancel"
            NSLog(@"Canceled");
            break;
        case EKEventEditViewActionSaved:
            NSLog(@"Saved");
            [controller.eventStore saveEvent:controller.event span: EKSpanFutureEvents error:&error];
            break;
        case EKEventEditViewActionDeleted:
            // User tapped "delete"
            NSLog(@"Deleted");
            // delete the event from event list
            [self.events removeObject:thisEvent];
            // delete the event from event store
            [self.eventStore removeEvent:thisEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:nil];
            // reload the tableView
            [self.tableOutlet reloadData];
            break;
        default:
                NSLog(@"Default");
            break;
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Probably not a solution to your question, but beware of the difference between American English and UK English: the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/EventKitUI/Reference/EKEventEditViewDelegateRef/Reference/Reference.html) say it should be `EKEventEditViewActionCanceled`, not `EKEventEditViewActionCancelled`.

Comment: Also, you should be using the UIViewController methods `presentViewController:animated:completion:` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` in place of `presentModalViewController:animated:` and `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` respectively, as the latter two are marked as deprecated in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 7):

According to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKitUI/Reference/EKEventEditViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html),

> eventStore
>
> This property must be set before displaying the view.

So,

```
eventViewController.eventStore = <your event store>;
eventViewController.editViewDelegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController: eventViewController
                        animated: YES];
```

Comment: perfect answer if you forgot to bind eventStore to EKEventEditViewController which have permission to access calender.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  Problem was where I'd defined the `eventStore` - probably when you present the `eventViewController` you don't even see the Calendar property.

In `AppDelegate`:

```
  __eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
```

In your class (I put this in `viewDidLoad`):

```
if (self.eventStore == Nil){
    id appDelegate = (id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
    self.eventStore = [appDelegate eventStore];   
}
```

and finally put this in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` before you present the view

```
eventViewController.eventStore = [self eventStore];
```